# Force a window to open on the monitor it was launched from

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, displayfusion

**Setup:**

- 3 Monitors
- DisplayFusion for the extra task bars on secondary / tertiary monitors
- Win7

**Problem:**

On my my main monitor (`Monitor 1`) with the authentic Windows task bar, I have a visual studio Solution file pinned. On my secondary monitor (`Monitor 2`) I have a different Solution file pinned to the DF task bar. When I launch **either** file, Visual Studio launches on `Monitor 1`.

**What I would like to happen:**

Have files / applications will be launched on their respective monitors.

**What I've tried:**

Display Fusion has a "Window Location" tool to configure things like this... Except it's on an application basis, not individual files. So I can only tell it to open VS on a given monitor, rather than forcing file X on `Monitor 1` and file Y on `Monitor 2`. I've also dug through the Advanced Settings and cannot find anything related, nor can I seem to find other SU questions about this. Googling tends to return stuff like "Make Excel open multiple work books in different windows instead of tabs" and things like that.

**EDIT** I should also note that DF's tool to configure shortcuts pinned to non-primary task bars does have a "Force to this monitor" field... But again this is on an application level and not individual files.

Comment: There are several tools that do this.  Which of those tools have you ruled out?

Comment: I have not been able to find any that do this. As I said, trying to google for a solution has been unhelpful. Perhaps poor google skills. Could you share the names of some tools...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *.* in a Window Location rule to make it work for all applications. Then just set it to "Current Monitor," and "All Windows." That will cause any new window to open on the monitor that the mouse cursor is currently on.